# Is there a way to query select username on Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to query the session username using DML, e.g:

`SELECT user();`

I have read this [`current_user`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/session.html) function with Presto but did not work in Athena.

My goal is create a where clause based on user... Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <mytable> 
WHERE if(current_user=<some>, 'value', 'othervalue') = <column>
```

Comment: Not sure that there is something build in but maybe you can achieve something with [user defined functions](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/tree/master/athena-udfs)

Comment: @GuruStron seems interesting, i'm just concerned with pricing increase

Comment: It looks like this information is not available. It might be because Athena does not use standard Presto authentication, and the concept of a "user" could take many forms in AWS -- IAM User, IAM Role, STS credentials, etc. I guess they could provide an Access Key, but it might change between executions. To control what data a user can access, you can manage what access they have to objects in Amazon S3. Athena uses the current user's access permissions, so **if they can see it in S3, they can see it in Athena**.